# Capturing the contents of a Window using BitBlt

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screenshot

I was trying to capture a window (Windows 7) and for some reason can't seem to capture the Non Client areas of the selected window.

I could capture the whole screen and then cut the interesting portion out but in case the selected window is obscured by another window I get something I don't want.

The capture works fine for just the client area and I was wondering if there is a way to get the NC area as well.

I'm using the following code

```
CDC* pDc=GetDC();

pDc->SelectStockObject(BLACK_PEN);
pDc->SelectStockObject(BLACK_PEN);

pDc->Rectangle(0,0,400,400);

HWND hSrcWnd=(HWND)0x00071256;
HDC hCalDC=::GetDCEx(hSrcWnd,NULL,DCX_WINDOW);
RECT rtWindow;
::GetWindowRect(hSrcWnd,&rtWindow);

::StretchBlt(pDc->GetSafeHdc(),0,0,400,400,hCalDC,0,0,rtWindow.right-rtWindow.left,rtWindow.bottom-rtWindow.top,SRCCOPY);
::ReleaseDC(hSrcWnd,hCalDC);
ReleaseDC(pDc);
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've got a feeling that you can send the WM_PRINT message to the window, passing the HDC of a memDC in wParam. So you get the size of the window, make (a) a memDC and (b) HBTIMAP the size of your window. Select the bitmap into the HDC, call WM_PRINT, then do what you want with the memDC and the HBITMAP.

Comment: You may try to use the PrintWindow API, but bear in mind that you may sometimes get an "all black" Bitmap. Detecting that case and retrying it a bit later usually works.